# Glassfish log files analysis

Tags: java, glassfish, log-analysis

Can I get some recommendations for good log analysis software for Glassfish log files? Since it will not vary from application server to application server dramatically, I guess that there is a common solution for all servers.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I agree with lili.

I just began using [OtrosLogviewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/) and wanted to share the custom .pattern file that is needed to parse GF logs. The following .pattern file works for GF 2.1.1 logs:

```
type=log4j
customLevels=SEVERE=FATAL,WARNING=WARN,CONFIG=INFO,FINE=DEBUG,FINER=TRACE,FINEST=TRACE,INFO=INFO
pattern=[#|TIMESTAMP|LEVEL|PROP(A)|CLASS|_ThreadID=PROP(B);_ThreadName=THREAD;|MESSAGE
dateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ
name=Glassfish Logfile
charset=UTF-8
```

Dump the above in a `glassfish.pattern` file in the Otros install folder in `$olv-home\plugins\logimporters\`.

Then when you re-open Otros, you should see the following option :

[image]

More patterns on this thread : http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/issues/detail?id=97

Related question : [Remote log viewer for Java/Glassfish log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186922/remote-log-viewer-for-java-glassfish-log-files)

Answer (score 4):

I like [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/). It lets you define any formatter, trail log file and filter it by Class/Thread/Log Level/Time

Comment: I just began using OtrosLogviewer and wanted to share the custom .pattern file that works for me on GF 2.1.1 :

Answer (score 1):

[Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php) might be an option.

Comment: Good point, but this this links to the webpage of the tool. If the link becomes invalid, then one may not be able to download at all. So I think in this case it is ok. One can google for "Baretail" or "Baretail alternative" that time.